# cellForRowAtIndexPath loads 2 cells effecting my scrollView

Tags: swift, scrollview, tableview

I have a two equal sized images within scrollView in a tabelViewCell. I have paging enabled and in my scrollViewDidEndDecelarting I have the following to know what page (image) they are looking at.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var scrollViewPageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    imagePageNumber = scrollViewPageNumber + 1 // global variable and either 1 or 2      
}
```

I have a button on the top of the scrollView (not subview of scrollView) which once it's tapped will send the current image (1 or 2) to the next viewController where the person can view it in detail.

my problem: cellForRowAtIndexPath loads two cells so lets say that I'm viewing image 2 in cell 3 and start to scroll down where I can see cell 4 and if I tap on the slight viewable image in cell 4 (seguebutton to take to view image in detail) it will send image 2 instead of the default which is 1.

What is the best recommendation to fix this?

I'm not sure how to confront this problem. I've tried various different ways. since there is only one imagePageNumber global variable, should I use two?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you're having an issue with the reutilisation of cells by your `UITableView`.

Have you tried setting the `contentOffset` of your `UIScrollView` to `CGPoint.zeroPoint` on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: I just used: scrollView.contentOffSet = CGPoint.zeroPoint -- Things are still the way they are. I scroll to image 2 then i scroll down the tableview where I can see the tip of the next scrollview in the next cell and it's still doing the same. Is that how I should be using it? my imagePageNumber is global so it effects the next cell.

Comment: I see the confusion...The scrollView itself is not has not moved. It appears at (0,0) in ever cell. it's the global variable that holds the page number when the scrollView is moved which effects the next cell's scrollView

Comment: You may have to add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to make this clearer and help me help you